# How to pass a variable as an iterable to the join method in python3?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code -

```
NAME_OF_THE_FILE_COLS = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie', 'delta']

def get_header_line(file, line):
    list_of_cols_str = file.upper() + "_COLS"

    print("{}".format("".join(line.strip().split())))
    print("{}".format("".join(list_of_cols_str)))
    
    # I'd like to compare the above two strings here

line = "alpha    bravo   charlie     delta" + "\n"
get_header_line("name_of_the_file", line)
```

I'd like to pass the iterable `NAME_OF_THE_FILE_COLS` whose name is the value of the variable `list_of_cols_str` and not treat `list_of_cols_str` itself as the iterator.

Can this be achieved?

Thanks, SO.

Comment: "which is in the variable `list_of_cols_str`" - what does that mean?

Comment: There's a dirty hack: `list_of_cols_str = globals()[file.upper() + "_COLS"]`

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb - i have edited the question. Basically, the name of the iterable is the variable's value.